# Create a script compilation for visual studio solutions

Tags: visual-studio

I'm working on a project which is composed of four visual studio solutions.

I need to create a script in order to build the solutions one by one just by building the first one.

I have no idea what i'm supposed to use to do that (maybe the post build event property?), can you give me a lead ?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it an option to use a batch file executing devenv from command line? Otherwise msbuild can be automated to build more than one solution (again with a build workflow if using TFS or from command line).

Comment: makes no sense. why do you need a script to build the solutions?

Comment: Are you trying to build from the command line or from one of the VS solutions? From the command line, I'd suggest creating a new `.proj` file from scratch and building your solutions one at a time from there. Search for MSBuild tutorials - it's actually pretty easy to put together simple MSBuild project files.

Comment: Batch file?  PowerShell?  Personally I like to use Ruby Rake for my automated builds.  But anything which can execute an msbuild.exe command will do the trick.

Comment: The solutions are depending on each other, some need other to be build so there is an order to respect and I was asked to do that so we don't have to build solutions one by one

Comment: How many projects are in each solution?

Comment: I'm trying to build from one of the VS solutions

Comment: the number of projects changes with the solutions

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio uses a system called MSBuild for its Solution and Project files. A Solution or Project file is really just a very simple MSBuild script. These text files can be hand edited, and can become much more complicated than the simple Solution/Project scenario created for you by Visual Studio. A properly configured build file will allow you to open any of your Solutions in Visual Studio, and build your projects with the existing tools as if things were still much simpler.

Read through the documentation here to get started:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5.aspx